# SQL Server get delta items

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, enterprise, sqlperformance

I have a many-million-records table having an integer primary key defined.
I also have a not-so-many-million IDs that are in the "black list". They are stored in memory (read from a file on disk).

I have to select the records that are NOT in the black list, that is, all the records whose ID is not in my black list.

I solved this using a temp table (single column: ID) to insert the unwanted IDs then select all records whose IDs are not in this table.

My main concern is performance:

1. Inserting so many record in temp table.
2. Selecting the item not being in temp table.

**EDIT**
At the moment I use a temp table like this:

1. create the temp table with a single column (ID)
2. fill the temp table with IDs
3. create a nonclustered index on column
4. get the delta items with a query similar to this:

select m.id from mytable m where m.id not in (seelct id from #tempTable)

Comment: Is the "black list" file static?  If so, you could add a `BIT` column and flag the ID's in the large permanent table.  If the "black list" file is not static....then what is the file format?  If it's a csv or fixed width fields, you could skip step 1 and read the ID's from the black list file via `OPENROWSET`.

Comment: I can't see an issue the with size of the temp table, but as you haven;t provided any performance stats, it's difficult to assess. Can you show us your query, or a simplified version of it. It would be useful to see how you are excluding the records, is it via joins, exists, in(...) clause etc. Also, your temp table creation might be useful to see. Perhaps an index would be useful?

Comment: @DMason no, the black list is not static, it is obtained dynamically. Also, the list is on my app server while the sql server runs on a separate, remote sql server machine, so I cannot reliably read the data from disk

Answer (score 0):

The best option you have here is to add a column to flag each row whether it is blacklisted or not ( ex: call it isBlockListed), and keep this column up-to-date.

You can also add an unclustered index to this flag so you can quickly select your data where isBlockListed = ture / false.